# A question about analytic function on the neighbourhood of spectrum sp(x).

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am reading a paper about operator theory. But i meet with a problem.

Let x be a element of Banach alegebra A and f be a arbitrary function analytic on the neighbourhood of sp(x) (sp(x) is the spectrum of x). **Then, the author says that f has only a finite number of zeros in sp(x).** But I don't understand why this conclusion holds... Someone could help me to do some explaination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectrum of an element in a Banach algebra is always compact. See any book on Banach algebras, for example Douglas' *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory.*

Then the statement follows because no (nonzero) analytic function can have an infinite number of zeros on a compact set. If it did, those zeros would have an accumulation point, and by the identity theorem $f$ would be the constant zero function.

I suppose there are some issues to take care of if the neighborhood isn't connected, but this is the essential idea.

Comment: i am sorry, i forget to say the assumption that f is non-constant on each component of its domain of definition. Does this hypothesis make some difference?

Comment: @Yankai Yes, that fixes it.

Comment: thanks, and could you explain to me whether the analytic function f, which is non-constant on each component of its domain of definition, has any difference to the analytic function f without it?

Comment: @Yankai I'm not sure what you're asking. My answer shows that the function would have to be constant on at least 1 component. This produces the necessary contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Because the spectrum is compact. If it had infinitely many zeroes, then those zeros would have a limit point, so your function would be identically zero (since it is analytic)

Comment: i am sorry, i forget to say the assumption that f is non-constant on each component of its domain of definition. Does this hypothesis make some difference?